# How to aggregate two or more columns into one column of type array in BigQuery?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I have this table:

| OrganizationUnitSetID | OrganizationUnitSetName | OrganizationUnitID | OrganizationUnitLevel1 | OrganizationUnitLevel2 | OrganizationUnitLevel3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49 | Switzerland | 46 | 77 | null | null |
| 49 | Switzerland | 46 | 47 | 48 | 76 |
| 49 | Switzerland | 46 | 47 | 48 | 59 |

And I need to generate a SQL in BigQuery that creates this view:

| OrganizationUnitSetID | OrganizationUnitSetName | OrganizationUnitID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 49 | Switzerland | 46 |
|  |  | 77 |
|  |  | 47 |
|  |  | 48 |
|  |  | 76 |
|  |  | 59 |

That means, bring the 4 columns:

- OrganizationUnitID
- OrganizationUnitLevel1
- OrganizationUnitLevel2
- OrganizationUnitLevel3

Into one column Array.
I am close to that but the problem is in these two `NULL` values on the first row.

Answer (score 1):

> I am close to that but the problem is in these two NULL values on the first row.

*ARRAY_AGG* with *IGNORE NULLS* will resolve this problem.

> bring the 4 columns in nto one column Array.

For this, you can try one of followings.

1. *UNNEST*

```sql
SELECT OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT org IGNORE NULLS) OrganizationUnitID 
  FROM sample_table,
UNNEST ([OrganizationUnitID, OrganizationUnitLevel1, OrganizationUnitLevel2, OrganizationUnitLevel3]) org
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

2. *UNPIVOT*

```sql
SELECT OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT org IGNORE NULLS) OrganizationUnitID 
  FROM sample_table UNPIVOT(org FOR org_level IN (
    OrganizationUnitID, OrganizationUnitLevel1, OrganizationUnitLevel2, OrganizationUnitLevel3
  ))
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

3. *UNION ALL*

```sql
SELECT OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT org IGNORE NULLS) OrganizationUnitID 
  FROM (
    SELECT OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName, OrganizationUnitID AS org FROM sample_table UNION ALL
    SELECT OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName, OrganizationUnitLevel1 AS org FROM sample_table UNION ALL
    SELECT OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName, OrganizationUnitLevel2 AS org FROM sample_table UNION ALL
    SELECT OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName, OrganizationUnitLevel3 AS org FROM sample_table
  )
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another fancy option  - to avoid explicit typing of multiple UnitID and UnitLevelNN columns:

```
select OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName, 
  array_agg(distinct id) as OrganizationUnitID
from your_table t, unnest(regexp_extract_all(
  format('%t', 
    (select as struct * except(OrganizationUnitSetID, OrganizationUnitSetName) from unnest([t]))
  ), r'\d+')
) id
group by 1, 2
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]